# I'm trying to install caffe, and "sudo make all" command crashes

Tags: makefile, caffe

I'm trying to install caffe, and "make all" command crashes on this line:

> ```
> coe@coe:~/deep-learning/caffe$ sudo make all
> [sudo] password for coe: 
> NVCC src/caffe/layers/hdf5_output_layer.cu
> make: /usr/local/cuda/bin/nvcc: Command not found
> Makefile:595: recipe for target '.build_release/cuda/src/caffe/layers/hdf5_output_layer.o' failed
> make: *** [.build_release/cuda/src/caffe/layers/hdf5_output_layer.o] Error 127
> ```

This is my screenshot after getting error from sudo make all command:

[image]

Comment: Please don't screenshot text output. Copy-paste the text.

Answer (score 1):

Your operating system does not recognize nvcc command.

To verify this run command `/usr/local/cuda/bin/nvcc --version`.
If it fails, it will mean that:

1. path to executable is wrong
2. program is not installed at all on your OS

Verify if it can be installed through the package manager.

Comment: Ok, I will try .. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

From the [Caffe installation instructions](http://caffe.berkeleyvision.org/installation.html):

> Caffe requires the CUDA nvcc compiler to compile its GPU code and CUDA
>   driver for GPU operation. To install CUDA, go to the NVIDIA CUDA
>   website and follow installation instructions there. Install the
>   library and the latest standalone driver separately; the driver
>   bundled with the library is usually out-of-date. Warning! The 331.*
>   CUDA driver series has a critical performance issue: do not use it.

Your system does not have nvcc. Install it.

Comment: More generally... when installing something from source, read the installation docs.

Comment: Actually I have already cuda installed but it is not enable mode...So anyone please tell me how to enable cuda in gpu.